# Upgrade to DotNetOpenAuth 3.4.6.10357 causes "CS1501: No overload for method 'OpenIdSelectorScripts' takes 3 arguments" error

Tags: overloading, dotnetopenauth

I have recently upgraded my DotNetOpenAuth.dll to the newest version and now when I run my site I am getting this error:

CS1501: No overload for method 'OpenIdSelectorScripts' takes 3 arguments

and the line that it is on is:

<%= Html.OpenIdSelectorScripts(this, options, null) %>

Does anyone know what the correction for this should be now? Or what might have changed with the new dll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newest version removed the first parameter (Page).  You can delete `this,` and it should work.

Comment: Thanks Andrew! That worked and once I deleted the "this," it gave me another error on the selector buttons but again I just had to remove the "this.Page" there too. Everything is working perfect now. Just curious, did DotNetOpenAuth say anything about removing that on the download page?

Comment: No, unfortunately this breaking change was undocumented.  We're try to avoid that -- I don't know how this one slipped through the cracks.